# Merge Javascript object

Tags: javascript, hash, merge, concatenation, javascript-objects

I have and object1 with a unknown key name and i need to merge with other object2.
The secure point is that unknown key is not present in the object2 so, never gonna be key names conflicts.

```
var object1 = {
 id: 1,
 name: "myname",
 boleanSample : true
}


var object2 = {
 unknownKeyName : "UnknownValue"
}
```

I want to merge object2 into object1 and get this

```
var object1 = {
 id: 1,
 name: "myname",
 boleanSample : true,
 unknownKeyName = "UnknownValue"
}
```

Please, vanilla Javascript only.
If the response require the creation of an new object3 is totally fine :)

PD: I checked these links before post the question:

- [Merge Javascript Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744946/merge-javascript-objects)   *( uses arrays... )*
- [Merging Javascript Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217485/merging-javascript-objects) *( Just for known keys, not useful for this case )*
- [Merging Javascript Objects on Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700636/merging-javascript-objects-on-property) *( Bad post, no sense )*

No duplication at all for those :)

Comment: `for( var k in object2) object1[k] = object2[k];`...?

Comment: What makes you think that the `mergeObjectInto` function from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32239489/1048572) only worked on known keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `Object.keys` with `Array#forEach`

```js
var object1 = {
  id: 1,
  name: "myname",
  boleanSample: true,
};

var object2 = {
  unknownKeyName: "UnknownValue" //correct typo here
};
Object.keys(object2).forEach(function(key) {
  object1[key] = object2[key];
});
console.log(object1);
```

Comment: Ok guys thank you so much but what can i do now ?
 Niet the Dark Absol  comment a valid solution, but
@gurvinder372 and Rayon  posted a valid solution also.

Maybe some update with both ways ? 

And someone know which one is better/faster/performance advantage :) ?

Comment: @HéctorLeón, Gurvinder was quickest among all..Go with his post :)

Answer (score 0):

This merge function should do it. Just remember to add the object you want to append two first.

```js
var object1 = {
 id: 1,
 name: "myname",
 boleanSample : true
}


var object2 = {
 unknownKeyName : "UnknownValue"
}

function mergeObjects(a,b){
  for(var bi in b) {
    if(b.hasOwnProperty(bi)) {
      if(typeof a[bi] === "undefined") {
        a[bi] = b[bi];
      }
    }
  }
}
mergeObjects(object1,object2);
console.log(object1);
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, but i tried and not working

Answer (score 0):

> Step I: loop over the properties.
>
> Step II: try and check if object
>
> Step III: if true, stimulate function on obj[prop] and check, else
>   just take check.
>
> Step IV: if there was an error obj[prop] = check;
>
> Step V: return obj

```js
/*functions*/
function objectConcat(o1, o2) {
  for (var v in o2) {
    try {
      o1[v] = (o2[v].constructor == Object) ? objectConcat(o1[v], o2[v]) : o2[v];
    } catch (e) {
      o1[v] = o2[v];
    }
  }
  return o1;
}

/*objects*/
var object1 = {
  id: 1,
  name: "myname",
  boleanSample: true,
}

var object2 = {
  unknownKeyName: "UnknownValue" /*mistake straighten*/
}

/*code*/

console.log(objectConcat(object2, object1));
```